# react-native start crashes with error npm[11708]: c:\ws\src\util-inl.h:369: Assertion `!(n > 0) || (ret != nullptr)' failed

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm

I am trying run react-native app. when I run `npx react-native start` server start, displays react logo and crashes with error

```
npm[11708]: c:\ws\src\util-inl.h:369: Assertion `!(n > 0) || (ret != nullptr)' failed.
```

I'm using windows 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what happened. I was using older version of Nodejs and npm. I updated Nodejs to version 16.13.0, and it worked like magic.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, and trying this does not work for me.

> I updated Nodejs to version 16.13.0, and it worked like magic.

But it gave me an idea of how to fix it.

Eventually, I realized I was using the wrong Node.js installation package.

Windows 10 may use the x64 installation package.

- node-v16.14.2-x64.msi(√)
- node-v16.14.2-x86.msi(×)